# Why AWS APIG returns Authorization errors on incorrect endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, aws-api-gateway-v2

While invoking an endpoint which is not configured in APIG and supplying an Authorization header (JWT token), the APIG responds with

```
{
"message": "Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header. Authorization=eyJraWQiOiJQK0"
```

}

Any reasons for validating auth before endpoint path. I believe invoking any non-exisiting endpoint should result in a 404, but thats not the case apparently.
Even if it validates the auth token first it should not respond with this because I am passing it a perfectly valid and active JWT token.

Any ideas on why this is configured this way?

Answer (score 0):

AWS API Gateway responds with a 403 error even for non-existent resources, as stated [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden) and [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-authentication-token-errors). 
I suspect this is for security reasons: providing a 404 response would implicitly reveal the API structure.
Ideally, this prevents an attacker from brute-forcing the API structure by searching for paths that return a 404 instead of a 403.

Comment: That is the case probably. Seems like an anti-pattern. Is there a way of overriding this default behaviour. I tried overriding the gateway error responses section for various error cases but this one is not configurable.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to override this behaviour...